# Java - Read files outside a jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm in troubles.

I worked on a project on a wiktionary dump (that is a reaaaally huge file). Requirements asked that the dump file had to be passed as argument from command line. For making it easier I worked on NetBeans, I set all the parameters, put the dump file into the 'src' folder and everything went fine.

Requirements asked that the project had to be delivered as a jar file. I'm quite a newbie with jars, so I just copied netbeans src folder, compiled the code (from shell), removed the dump file -as it wasn't needed to be into the jar - and just did "compress as jar file".

Now comes the problem: When I run it from shell I get `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` caused by a `java.net.MalformedURLException` . I think the problem is that it looks for the dump only inside the jar, but actually the dump will be outside.. How can I fix it?

Don't know if it matters.. I'm working on ubuntu

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: it is really a lot of code! The statement on which it fails is `XMLStreamReader reader = 
        factory.createXMLStreamReader(
        ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(dump));`
where dump is the argument passed from shell

Comment: ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream only looks in the Jar. You need to produce the InputStream another way

Comment: Are you sure about **getSystemResourceAsStream**..?. Thought is it handle resources which is placed inside the jar, may be in classpath also. If you want read a file which outside of jar go with File.

Comment: I found that piece of code online, as I was learning how to use XML parser. So here was the problem. Thanks guys! You're the best! :)

Comment: @subash You are correct. It will find any resource where it would find a class, i.e. the class path. My comment was over-simplified to his case

Comment: So there is no way to make it work without editing the code?